# How to increase recombination lifetime in LASER?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser

In a semiconductor laser, the light emission happens due to recombination in a pn junction. But the recombination lifetime in a pn junction is very small as a result of which the charge carriers do not get enough time to recombine and emit a photon. Explain how this recombination lifetime in a on junction can be increased, so that more photons are generated?

Comment: Repost of previous (deleted?) question.

Comment: I don't think so? (char limit)

Comment: Well, there was a nearly exact match yesterday...

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/606214/how-can-i-increase-recombination-time-of-a-pn-junction?r=SearchResults - this one. Both in the same class?

Comment: There are lots of references at the end of this Wikipedia article. [Carrier generation and recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_generation_and_recombination)

Answer (score 1):

Radiative lifetime will decrease by:

1. Increasing the spacial overlap of the electron and hole wavefunctions. For example by adding quantum well or quantum dots into the junction region to act as radiative recombination centres.
2. [Purcell Effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purcell_effect) increase the spontaneous emission rate by enhancing the optical density of states at a specific region and over a targeted bandwidth.